# Saving the outputs from tabyl function

Tags: r

*I used the following function to calculate the number of observations and percentages for all categorical variables in a dataset. I was wondering how I can save the output in an excel file/one sheet.*

```
dat <- structure(list(ID = c(55L, 67L, 83L, 78L, 43L, 29L), color1 = c("red", 
"yellow", "blue", "red", "green", "yellow"), color2 = c("blue", 
NA, "yellow", "yellow", NA, "green"), color3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
"blue", NA, NA), shape1 = c("circle", "triangle", "circle", "square", 
"square", "circle"), shape2 = c("triangle", NA, NA, "circle", 
"circle", "triangle"), size = c("small", "medium", "large", "large", 
"small", "medium")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

lapply(dat, function(x) tabyl(x))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function creates a list of objects that are both dataframes and tabyls. One option is to use the package `openxlsx` to save all dataframes/tabyls in that list to a single `.xlsx` file, with each object in the list having its own sheet in the `.xlsx` file.

Alternatively, since each object in that list is also a dataframe, `write.csv` will also work as well on the individual dataframes/tabyls.

```
library(janitor)
library(openxlsx)

dat <- structure(list(ID = c(55L, 67L, 83L, 78L, 43L, 29L), 
                      color1 = c("red", "yellow", "blue", "red", "green", "yellow"), 
                      color2 = c("blue", NA, "yellow", "yellow", NA, "green"), 
                      color3 = c(NA, NA, NA, "blue", NA, NA), 
                      shape1 = c("circle", "triangle", "circle", "square", "square", "circle"), 
                      shape2 = c("triangle", NA, NA, "circle", "circle", "triangle"), 
                      size = c("small", "medium", "large", "large", "small", "medium")), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

output <- lapply(dat, function(x) tabyl(x))
class(output)
#> [1] "list"
class(output[[1]])
#> [1] "tabyl"      "data.frame"

write.xlsx(output, "myoutput.xlsx")
write.csv(output[[1]], "myoutput1.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

##### update

I have included code below that binds all the dataframes from `output` into a single dataframe.

```
library(tidyverse)

# apply OP's function
output <- lapply(dat, function(x) tabyl(x, show_na = FALSE))

# make sure that the x variable in each dataframe is a character
# in every dataframe in `output`
output <- lapply(output, function(y) { mutate(y, x = as.character(x)) })

# bind all dataframes together into one dataframe
output <- bind_rows(output, .id = "x")

# write out into an Excel object - write.csv will also work
write.xlsx(output, "myoutput.xlsx")
```

Comment: thanks so much but I got the following error: Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE, : arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 4, 3, 5, 6.  and I need to have all tables in one sheet.

Comment: I have updated my answer based on your new dataset; however; I can't reproduce your error message. Are your versions of R and RStudio (as well as relevant packages) up to date?

Comment: Also please update your original question that you want all the tables in one sheet and provide an example of what you would like your final output to look like.

Comment: @ 
jrcalabrese, thanks for the reply. I have already mentioned it that I need it in excel format.

Comment: Does `write.xlsx` not adequately produce an object in an Excel format? Or do you mean something different? I'm confused about what you want your final output to look like exactly (e.g., the structure, the column names, etc.).

Comment: @ 
jrcalabrese, I need to have all results (the frequenct tables of all variables) in one page. I tried write.csv but when it was empty. I think we need to use another function in order to save the results in a file.

Comment: I have updated my answer to combine all the dataframes from `output` into a single dataframe, which can then be read out using `write.xlsx` or `write.csv`.